# Trouble reading character in String (Java)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have some trouble in getting Java to read the first character in a String.  I have here included the code up to this point (the code beyond this is, I don't think, relevant at all):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SeveralDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many dice do you want to use? ");

        int numberOfDice = input.nextInt();

        SeveralDice game = new SeveralDice(numberOfDice);

        System.out.print("You have 0 points.  Another try(y/n)? ");

        boolean turn = true;
        String answerInput;
        char answer;
        int lastValue = 0;

        while (turn) {
            answerInput = input.nextLine();
            answer = answerInput.charAt(0);
            if (answer == 'y') {. . . . .
```

And then the code continues.  However, when I run the program, I get the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at SeveralDice.main(SeveralDice.java:25)*
```

Line 25 is the line `answer = answerInput.charAt(0);`.  So obviously something goes wrong here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that entering the integer for "How many dice..." also triggers the call to nextLine() to read a blank line (since you are pressing enter after you wrote the integer) and so you are reading a string with 0 characters. I suggest you replace:

```
int numberOfDice = input.nextInt();
```

with

```
int numberOfDice = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Comment: @Kristian: Glad to help. Don't forget to select accepted answer if it solved your problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because when you do:

```
int numberOfDice = input.nextInt();
```

You read in the `int` the user enters but the `\n` is still in the input stream.

The first call to `input.nextLine()` in your loop tokenizes on `\n` so it's reading in a blank line, thus `answerInput` has a zero length. `nextLine()` differs from `nextInt()` in that it reads in an entire line as a `String` and strips the trailing `\n` from the intput.

As others have posted, checking the length of `answerInput` will solve the problem. You can also simply call `input.nextLine()` after getting your `int` from `nextInt()`

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is really useful!  I've been struggling with understanding this for a while, and this makes a lot of sense now :)